# reading textfile into an array, printing via function

Tags: c, arrays, function

My issue is that I'm trying to read characters from a text file into an array. The original size of the array is longer than the number of entries in the text file but I only want to print out the indices of the array that are used. The array is then supposed to be printed by the function printCharacterArray.

The program compiles and runs fine and even prints the blank lines where the characters in the array should be. The issue apparently is that none of the text file entries are being read into the array. Suggestions? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILENAME "hello.txt"

#define SIZE 200

//function prototype
int printCharacterArray(char encrypted[], int k);

int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    int key;
    int k = 0;
    int retValue;
    FILE *message;

    //Create array
    char encrypted[SIZE]={'\0'};    

    //Open file
    message = fopen(FILENAME,"r");

    //check that file opened
    if (message == NULL){
        printf("File didn't open.");
        fclose(message);
    }else{
        fscanf(message,"%d\n",&key);
        //set loop to read rest of file
    while (!feof(message)){
        fscanf(message,"%c\n",&encrypted[k]);
        k++;
        }
    fclose(message);    
    }
    //Call and catch function   
    retValue = printCharacterArray(encrypted, k);
    if (retValue==0){
        printf("Exit failure, retValue = 0");       
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else{
        printf("Exit success, retValue != 0");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    }

   //Function Definition

    int printCharacterArray(char encrypted[ ], int k){
        int g;
        if (k==0){
            printf("EXIT FAILURE, k = 0");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }else{
            for (g=0; g<=k; g++){
            printf("%c\n",encrypted[k]);
            }
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) `retValue==0` --> `retValue==EXIT_FAILURE` 2) `g<=k` --> `g<k`

Comment: You should print `encrypted[g]` instead of `encrypted[k]`. (Took me a while to spot, because I'm used to `i`, `j` and `k` as loop counters and `n` and `m` as numbers of things.)

Answer (score 0):

fscanf(message,"%c",&encrypted[k]); No new line '\n'
and encrypted[g]